# Understanding confusing

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses, traversable

I've been thinking about whether there's some method that could be added to `Traversable` to make it compose more cheaply in the presence of expensive functors. The inspiration was [`Control.Lens.Traversal.confusing`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html#v:confusing), which uses a special `Applicative` to do something similar.

```
confusing :: Applicative f => LensLike (Curried (Yoneda f) (Yoneda f)) s t a b -> LensLike f s t a b
```

Unfortunately, `confusing` really lives up to its name—I don't understand what it's actually doing. In particular, I have no intuition about `Curried`.

Furthermore, `confusing` has a CPS flavor to it, which suggests it's probably too strict for my purpose. `Yoneda` can be swapped out for `Coyoneda` to enhance laziness, but I have no idea what to do about the `Curried`.

Comment: Not really a full answer, but some little bits of intuition I've skimmed from the docs: given `fx :: f a` then `(<*> fx) :: forall r. f (a -> r) -> f r`, ripe to be passed to `Curried`. So it's a bit like a higher-order encoding of the application operator. Furthermore, looking at [its Applicative instance](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/kan-extensions-5.0.1/docs/src/Data-Functor-Day-Curried.html#line-48) you can see that `<*>` is implemented using `.`, like difference lists' `mappend`, which I guess is what the docs mean when they talk about reassociating `<*>` calls.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson, I'm not really after reassociating the `<*>` calls, per se, so maybe `confusing` isn't the right model. What I really want, I think, is to replace `f <$> m <*> (g <$> n)` with `(\mr nr -> f mr (g nr)) <$> m <*> n`, and to do that recursively. I wonder if I need to look less at `Traversable` and more at `Applicative` itself.

Comment: It's discussed in subsection _8.4.2_ of [_Generic Deriving of Generic Traversals_](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.06798)

Comment: I also want to point out, that `Yoneda` has the type of `flip fmap` applied to a single argument. `Curried` has the type of `flip (<*>)` applied to a single argument. `(<$> ..) :: forall x. (A -> x) -> F x` and `(<*> ..) :: forall x. F (A -> x) -> F x`.